# Updating which python my django app uses

Tags: django, python-2.7

The django app running on localhost in a virtualenv uses the default python version 2.7.3 that is under `/usr/bin/` but I installed Python 2.7.9 under ~/.opt/bin/python2.7. I updated the `$PATH` but I want the django app to use the locally installed python version by default.

Please help me understand how to make that happen. Thank you.

Comment: `~/.opt/bin/python2.7 manage.py runserver`

Comment: Thank you @Wtower but that gives an error that it can't find django.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new virtualenv using Python 2.7.  Use the -p flag to point to the python installation you want for that virtual environment, and then pip install django within that virtual environment.